# How to apply NLTK word_tokenize library on a Pandas dataframe for Twitter data?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, nltk, tokenize

This is the Code that I am using for semantic analysis of twitter:-

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

df=pd.read_csv('twitDB.csv',header=None, 
sep=',',error_bad_lines=False,encoding='utf-8')

hula=df[[0,1,2,3]]
hula=hula.fillna(0)
hula['tweet'] = hula[0].astype(str) 
+hula[1].astype(str)+hula[2].astype(str)+hula[3].astype(str) 
hula["tweet"]=hula.tweet.str.lower()

ho=hula["tweet"]
ho = ho.replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True) 
ho=ho.replace('\.+', '.', regex=True)
special_char_list = [':', ';', '?', '}', ')', '{', '(']
for special_char in special_char_list:
ho=ho.replace(special_char, '')
print(ho)

ho = ho.replace('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',regex=True)
ho =ho.replace(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', regex=True)
ho =ho.replace('\'"',regex=True)

lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
stem = PorterStemmer()
fg=stem.stem(a)

eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 
ho = ho.to_frame(name=None)
a=ho.to_string(buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, header=True, 
index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None, float_format=None, 
sparsify=False, index_names=True, justify=None, line_width=None, 
max_rows=None, max_cols=None, show_dimensions=False)
wordList = word_tokenize(fg)                                     
wordList = [word for word in wordList if word not in eng_stopwords]  
print (wordList)
```

Input i.e. a :-

```
                                              tweet
0     1495596971.6034188::automotive auto ebc greens...
1     1495596972.330948::new free stock photo of cit...
```

getting output ( wordList) in this format:-

```
tweet
 0
1495596971.6034188
:
:automotive
auto
```

I want the output of a row in a row format only. How can I do it?
If you have a better code for semantic analysis of twitter please share it with me.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In short:

```
df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

Or if you want to add another column to store the tokenized list of strings:

```
df['tokenized_text'] = df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

There are tokenizers written specifically for twitter text, see http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.casual

To use `nltk.tokenize.TweetTokenizer`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
tt = TweetTokenizer()
df['Text'].apply(tt.tokenize)
```

Similar to:

- [How to apply pos_tag_sents() to pandas dataframe efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674573/how-to-apply-pos-tag-sents-to-pandas-dataframe-efficiently)
- [how to use word_tokenize in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098040/how-to-use-word-tokenize-in-data-frame)
- [How to apply pos_tag_sents() to pandas dataframe efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674573/how-to-apply-pos-tag-sents-to-pandas-dataframe-efficiently)
- [Tokenizing words into a new column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119954/tokenizing-words-into-a-new-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [Run nltk sent_tokenize through Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922145/run-nltk-sent-tokenize-through-pandas-dataframe)
- [Python text processing: NLTK and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784004/python-text-processing-nltk-and-pandas)

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.

Comment: Your questions are going to get closed easily if you don't strip the irrelevant parts of your code and only post information crucial to your question. Make edits to the new question you ask ;P

Comment: Sure, will do that and ask again. Thanks :)

Comment: @alvas, do you know why I am getting: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when running your code above on my pandas dataframe column with text. My only difference is I am using sent_tokenizer to just split into sentences as opposed to words