# Converting 'CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader' into dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I want to convert `movie_reviews` dataset from `nltk.corpus` into dataframe.
The purpose is to use this data for sentiment analysis. 
while converting the data using pandas, I'm getting an error:

```
    from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
    import pandas as pd

    mr=movie_reviews
    movie=pd.DataFrame(mr)
```

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: @alvas, now that you've shown how to do it, maybe you should now remove your "it's not possible" claim...

Comment: Ah, it should be "I don't think it's possible to simply initialize it that way" =)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to simply initialize it that way". An NLTK's `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` object isn't a `dtype` for `pandas`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NLTK's `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` object isn't a `dtype` for `pandas`.

That being said, you can convert the movie reviews into list of tuples and then populate a dataframe as such:

```
import pandas as pd

from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as mr

reviews = []
for fileid in mr.fileids():
    tag, filename = fileid.split('/')
    reviews.append((filename, tag, mr.raw(fileid)))

df = pd.DataFrame(reviews, columns=['filename', 'tag', 'text'])
```

[out]:

```
>>> df.head()
          filename  tag                                               text
0  cv000_29416.txt  neg  plot : two teen couples go to a church party ,...
1  cv001_19502.txt  neg  the happy bastard's quick movie review \ndamn ...
2  cv002_17424.txt  neg  it is movies like these that make a jaded movi...
3  cv003_12683.txt  neg   " quest for camelot " is warner bros . ' firs...
4  cv004_12641.txt  neg  synopsis : a mentally unstable man undergoing ...
```

To process the `text` column, see [How to NLTK word_tokenize to a Pandas dataframe for Twitter data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173624/how-to-nltk-word-tokenize-to-a-pandas-dataframe-for-twitter-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplified answer:

```
from nltk.corpus import reuters # Imports Reuters corpus
reuters_cat= reuters.categories() # Creates a list of categories

docs=[] 
for cat in reuters_cat: # We append tuples of each document and categories in a list
    t1=reuters.sents(categories=cat) # At each iteration we retrieve all documents of a given category
    for doc in t1:
        docs.append((' '.join(doc), cat)) # These documents are appended as a tuple (document, category) in the list

reuters_df=pd.DataFrame(docs, columns=['document', 'category']) #The data frame is created using the generated tuple.

reuters_df.head()
```

Apologies for not adding a dataframe head sample as I'm still new to stackoverflow