# Tokenize content of column in csv using Panda and Nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I have a csv file with three columns, and I want to loop through the content of the column 'text' and tokenize (splitting by strings of only letters and apostrophes) every cell from it.

This does not seem to work:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[a-zA-Z'`éèî]+")
for x in data['text']:
     x = tokenizer.tokenize(x)
```

The error I get is TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What is the content of `data['text']`? If it's neither a string nor `bytes`, what is it? Try `type(x)` before the line that tokenizes.

Comment: Firstly, use Python3, then try `data['text'] = data['text'].astype(str)`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173624/how-to-nltk-word-tokenize-to-a-pandas-dataframe-for-twitter-data/44174565#44174565

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=regexptokenizer#module-nltk.tokenize):

> Caution: when tokenizing a Unicode string, make sure you are not using
>   an encoded version of the string (it may be necessary to decode it
>   first, e.g. with s.decode("utf8").

So try:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[a-zA-Z'`éèî]+")
for x in data['text']:
     x = tokenizer.tokenize(x.decode("utf8"))
```